# Tricking Linux apps about current time with environment variables

Tags: linux, environment-variables

Sometimes it is possible to trick a Linux app by calling it like this:

```
HOME=/tmp/foo myapp
```

This would make myapp think **/tmp/foo** is the home directory, it won't try to get the user id, find its home directory via **getpwent()**.

This is useful when myapp must be forced to dump some of its config files into a non-standard location different than **~**.

A similar trick can be done like this:

```
LANG=foo LC_ALL=bar myapp
```

This is useful when myapp needs to be called once with a different locale without having to make the change persistent by using the **export** bash built-in or even modify stuff in **/etc/profile**.

Is it possible to pull the same trick with time and date?
The goal is to make an app use another time than the system ones.
The final goal - to make timestamps that appear in logs/commit messages not being tied to the system time.

Comment: +1 on the question because it's an interesting idea with interesting use cases that I'd never considered. I'm just sorry I can't provide an answer.

Comment: For moderators: feel free to mark this question as duplicate of the one mentioned by Dennis Williamson in his answer.

Comment: Cross-site duplicates are not usually closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/138325/faking-the-date-for-a-specific-shell-session/138371#138371) from Stack Overflow suggests a library called `libfaketime`.